# C# test if SqlDataAdapter contains records

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado

I use ADO and new to C#.

This source shows records have been read whether successful or not. Works well if record/s found, never shows `MessageBox.Show("No Records")`

```
public static void readSqlData(String sSource)
{
    string strSelection = "SELECT * FROM " + sSource;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelection, cnn);

    if (da != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Records have been read");

        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No records \n" + strSelection);
    }
}
```

I have searched for "Test if SqlDataAdapter is empty".  I don't understand the answers.  Sorry, to easily confused.

Comment: checking for null makes no  sende, see if the datatable has any rows

Comment: code is ok. please check connection string have value.

Comment: The problem is that the ideas of a data adapter being empty or not is nonsensical. It's the `DataTable` that contains (or doesn't contain) data, not the data adapter. The data adapter executes commands to retrieve or save data. The very first thing you should have done was read the documentation for the `SqlDataAdapter` class and its members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether datatable rows count higher from zero or not.

```
public static void readSqlData(String sSource)
{
            string strSelection = "SELECT * FROM " + sSource;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSelection, cnn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Records have been read");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records \n" + strSelection);
            }
}
```

Comment: While checking the row count in the table is not necessarily wrong, that number was already returned by the `Fill` method, so ignoring that and then getting it from elsewhere is suboptimal. Also, this would not usually be the case but, if the table already contained data and you were retrieving additional data, the row count would not tell you whether more rows had been added unless you compared it to the old value. The result of `Fill` is always applicable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of why you need to read the documentation. If you had done that then you'd know that the `Fill` method returns the number of records retrieved.

```cs
if (myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable) > 0)
{
    // At least one record was retrieved.
}
else
{
    // No records were retrieved.
}
```